# How to make "spell check" be always on?

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to know if it's possible in my Sublime Text 2 editor to have the spell check facility be always turned on because by default it's off. So, every time I open a file, I always have to press the F6 key to get it back on which is, quite frankly, very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the menu bar:

`Preferences > Settings-Default > "spell_check": true`